# How to insert or update status when "when" condition failed in drools?

Tags: drools

In drools we have `when` and `then`. If a condition is satisfied, then we go to the `then` condition and update a status, like `obj.setStatus("transaction success", "review required")`.

But when the `when` condition is not satisfied, then I want to update `obj.setStatus("transaction Failed", "review not required")`.

How is this possible in Drools?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to initialize obj.status to "failed". After all rules have fired, you'll either still have this or the updated status showing "success".

If you need a rule firing, you can write a rule catching the unmodified fact:

```
rule "catch failures"
salience -999999
when
    $obj: MyFact( status == null ) // no initial value
then
    modify( $obj ){ setStatus("transaction Failed", "review not required") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single rule. If we do like that then our rules size will be increase.

```
//FailureMessage :- Equipment breakdown coverage size is greater than 0
```

rule  "CPP_ReviewLossControl"
ruleflow-group "CPPReview"
lock-on-active 
    when
        $commPolicy : CommlPolicyInfoBean();
        $STPRulesResponseBean:STPRulesResponseBean();
        $lobInfo: LOBInfoBean("CPP".equalsIgnoreCase(lob) && losses.size() >= 3) from $commPolicy.getLobs();
   then
        System.out.println("Creating Loss history task for AMR");
        $STPRulesResponseBean.getResultMap().put("CPP_ORD_LOSS_CNTRL",true);
end

//FailureMessage :-Business category should  be General Framing, Window or Window Framing, Stucco and/or EIFS application including masonry/drywall contractors., Roofing, Exterior Siding/Water Proofing/Caulking, Any other exterior finishing work.

rule  "CPP_ReviewBusinessCategory"
ruleflow-group "CPPReview"
lock-on-active 
    when
        $STPRulesResponseBean:STPRulesResponseBean();
        $commlPolicyInfoBean : CommlPolicyInfoBean();
        $lobInfo: LOBInfoBean("CPP".equalsIgnoreCase(lob)) from $commlPolicyInfoBean.getLobs();
        AccountInfoBean(businessCategoryCode =="23" && (primaryActivities contains ("23813") || primaryActivities contains ("23831") || primaryActivities contains "23816")) from $commlPolicyInfoBean.getAccountInfo()
then
        System.out.println("Creating Business category");
        $STPRulesResponseBean.getResultMap().put("CPP_REV_SPL_RISK",true);
end

and there is setFocus also.